# Lumen GET Requests Return 404 Error

Tags: php, lumen

```
define('ROUTE_BASE', 'lumen/public');

$app->get(ROUTE_BASE . '/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->welcome();
});

$app->get(ROUTE_BASE . '/test', function () use ($app) {
    return 'test data : 123 abc !';
});
```

When I access **'localhost/lumen/public/'** I can see the 'lumen welcome page'.

But if I try to access **'localhost/lumen/public/test'**, I receive the following error.

> Error: its not found(404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your lumen project must be put in webroot of your **localhost**,**domain** or **virtual host** not in subfolder of your webroot without edit your .htaccess.
for access your project in browser : **http://lumen.laravel.dev** not **http://lumen.laravel.dev/public/**

I hope this help. sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel expects the public directory to be the webroot of your domain. As this is not true in your case, you will need to make some alterations to your `.htaccess`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lumen/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also worth noting that instead of using a constant, you can use route groups to achieve the same functionality in your routes.php.

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'lumen/public'], function ($app) {
    $app->get('/', function ()  {
        //welcome
    });

    $app->get('test', function ()  {
        return 'test data : 123 abc !';
    });
});
```